# Variable is undefined because it is being instantiated before the API call is completed - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a weather app. There are two different api calls I need to make before I can receive the data needed to manipulate for my view.

I created a service that makes these api calls and sets up global variables for access from my different components. The first call is the geolocation api. After I receive the latitude and longitude parameters I can then make the second call to the weather api.

The problem I am having is my component is trying to access the global variable before my weather api call gets completed, rendering me with and undefined variable.

I've tried to use async/await but can't get it to work properly and just recently found a forkJoin rxjs method.

Currently the solution I did was to use a setTimeout function to wait about 1 sec before proceeding to the next line of code. I do not feel this is the best way to do this but it works.

Is there a better method I can look into and try?

**main-component.ts**

```
  currentlyForecast: string;

  lat: number;
  long: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGeo();
  }

  getGeo() {
    this.weather.getGeo()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.lat = data.latitude;
        this.long = data.longitude;
        this.getWeather(this.lat, this.long);
      });
  }

  getWeather(lat, long) {
    let location = { latitude: lat, longitude: long };

    this.weather.getWeather(location);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentlyForecast = this.weather.currentlyForecast;
      console.log(this.currentlyForecast);
    }, 700);
  }
```

**weather.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  // Weather parameters
  public currentlyForecast: any;
  public dailyForecast: any;
  public hourlyForecast: any;
  public minutelyForecast: any;

  private weatherUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/weather/data';
  private geoLocationUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/weather/geo';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getGeo() {
    return this.http.get(this.geoLocationUrl);
  }

  getWeather(location) {
    return this.http.post(this.weatherUrl, location, httpOptions)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.currentlyForecast = data.currently;
        this.dailyForecast = data.daily;
        this.hourlyForecast = data.hourly;
        this.minutelyForecast = data.minutely;
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.weather.getWeather(location);` what does this line do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  getWeather(location) {
    return this.http.post(this.weatherUrl, location, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
          console.log(data)
          this.currentlyForecast = data.currently;
          this.dailyForecast = data.daily;
          this.hourlyForecast = data.hourly;
          this.minutelyForecast = data.minutely;
          console.log(this.currentlyForecast);
          return this.currentlyForecast;
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do below changes in your code . :

```js
// modify your service like below :  

 getWeather(location) {
    return this.http.post(this.weatherUrl, location, httpOptions)
      .map((data: any) => {
        console.log(data)
        // you can keep  these variables if needed here or
        // move them to component file
        this.currentlyForecast = data.currently;
        this.dailyForecast = data.daily;
        this.hourlyForecast = data.hourly;
        this.minutelyForecast = data.minutely;
        
        return  this.currentlyForecast; // returning this because you have used in componenet file
      });
  }
  
  // Now in component modify your method like below : 
  
  getWeather(lat, long) {
    let location = { latitude: lat, longitude: long };

    this.weather.getWeather(location).subscribe((result:any)=>{
       //result will contain currentlyForecast value
      this.currentlyForecast = result;
      console.log(this.currentlyForecast);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks your code set me off towards the right direction I needed. I had to modify your code a bit by extending the observable with the pipe method before I could map out the results. I did not know you could map your data like this. I thought you had to use the subscribe method when calling an http call. I'll have to look deeper into this but can you give me a basic reason why you used map over subscribe in the service?

Comment: I think so. I found out about ReactiveX docs which I wasn't aware of before. I'm pretty new to developing and only know by the tutorials I've used. None of them really explained to me about Observables and ReactiveX.

Comment: @CuongVo  any async request has to be subscribed then only it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes:

This method returning a promise, the `Promise` has `then` and `catch` callbacks.

`getWeather(location): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.weatherUrl, location, httpOptions).ToPromise();
}`

Add this method in your `weather.service.ts`:

```
public setData(data: any): void {
    this.currentlyForecast = data.currently;
    this.dailyForecast = data.daily;
    this.hourlyForecast = data.hourly;
    this.minutelyForecast = data.minutely;
}
```

And in your `main-component.ts`

```
 getWeather(lat, long) {
    let location = { latitude: lat, longitude: long };

    this.weather.getWeather(location)
      .then((data) => {
        this.weather.setData(data);
        this.currentlyForecast = this.weather.currentlyForecast;
        console.log(this.currentlyForecast);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

We can see it working at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xodqxj?embed=1&file=src/app/weather.service.ts